# Flipkart Creating the Listing with the seller API

Tags: flipkart-api

I am Integrated with the Flipkart Seller API and Got the Sandbox and Production API access. But When I am Accessing the Sandbox API's for Creating My Listing I am getting this Response :

https://sandbox-api.flipkart.net/sellers/listings/v3

with Header : 
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization: Bearer 'access-token'

```
{
    "sku": {
        "product_id": "BOTFGNN8VSYFTDE",
        "price": {
            "mrp": 100,
            "selling_price": 100,
            "currency": "INR"
        },
        "tax": {
            "hsn": "39264099",
            "tax_code" : "GST_5"
        },
        "listing_status": "ACTIVE",
        "fulfillment_profile": "NON_FBF",
        "fulfillment": {
            "dispatch_sla": 1,
            "shipping_provider": "FLIPKART",
            "procurement_type": "REGULAR"
        },
        "packages": [
            {
                "name": "RHBUS001",
                "dimensions": {
                    "length": 1,
                    "breadth": 1,
                    "height": 1
                },
                "weight": 1,

                "notional_value": {
                    "amount": 1,
                    "unit": "PERCENTAGE"
                }
            }
        ],
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": "WH",
                "status": "ENABLED",
                "inventory": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And Getting the Response From API's Call :

```
{
    "sku": {
        "status": "FAILURE",
        "errors": [
            {
                "severity": "ERROR",
                "code": 25001,
                "description": "Invalid FSN BOTFGNN8VSYFTDE."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, would you share me how to get "product_id"

Comment: Hello @Ganesh, can you please help me out in oauth login as I am getting only error like Oops! Something went wrong Please go back to your client application and try again, or contact the owner and ask for support